# Python Error 13 when trying to download off SFTP to local machine path

Tags: python

I am getting Error 13 Access denied when I try to download off the SFTP onto my local machine.

When I break up everything step by step, everything seems to work. it connects succesfully to the SFTP and lists the directories and the local path also connects and lists correctly, however on  sftp.get(filepath, localpath) it gives me the access denied error.

if anyone is able to guide me - would be extremely appreciated

````
from os import listdir
import os
from threading import local
import paramiko
paramiko.util.log_to_file("Client_Update.log")

VersionNumber = input("Please enter the version number to download: ")
print("Version Number is " + VersionNumber)

# Create directory for Version
try:
    os.mkdir("C:\\ClientSoftware\\" +VersionNumber)
    print("Directory created successfully!")
except:
    print("Failed to create Directory")

# Open a transport
host,port = "host IP",22
transport = paramiko.Transport((host,port))

# Auth   
try: 
    username,password = "test","test123"
    transport.connect(None,username,password)

# Access SFTP    
    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
    print("...Connection Succesful")
    listdir()
except NameError:
    print("....Connection Failed")
except:
    print("An Error Occured - Please contact Admin for further details")

# Download
try :
    filepath = "/WebService/Client Software/Application Files/" + VersionNumber+"/"
    print("Version Found Succesfully!")
    dirlist = sftp.listdir(filepath)
    print ("Dirlist:", dirlist)
    
    try:
       
        localpath = "C:\\ClientSoftware\\" +VersionNumber+"\\motaDataClientSoftware.7z"
        print (localpath)
        print("local directory found succesfully!")
    except:
        print("Local Path not found, please check if localpath C:\ClientSoftware exists")
    try:
        sftp.get(filepath, localpath)
    except:
        print("An Error Occurred with downloading off SFTP")
        print(filepath, localpath)
except:
    print("FilePath Does not exist, Please check if path exists on SFTP and check your version Number exists")
  
# Close
try:
    if sftp: sftp.close()
    if transport: transport.close()
except:
    print("SFTP not open, failed to close")```
````

Comment: "When I break up everything step by step": you mean manually, on the command line, with plain sftp commands? Or do you code the Python steps one by one?

Comment: I mean manually on the command line

Comment: What is the actual error you get when the script fails? Because currently, you catch every and all errors, and hiding the actual error behind a basic error message.

Comment: File "C:\Users\joshua.segal\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 810, in get
    with open(localpath, "wb") as fl:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\ClientSoftware'

Comment: Note that `sftp.get()` seems to work only on files, not directories. I don't know paramiko, but that is what the documentation seems to suggest. But your `filepath` and `localpath` are directories.

Comment: "Permission denied: 'C:\\ClientSoftware'" suggests that either the permission already stops there, or otherwise the whole path is missing several subdirectories.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much - I added the file and extension and its working. thank you so much

Comment: So as a user with CMD or powershell, you can create a file in 'C:\ClientSoftware\...' just fine?

Comment: Oh, magic. Nice, easy peasy then.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the Paramiko manual (interpolating a bit), [`SFTP.get()`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.get) only works on files, not on directories.

Your input paths, however, are directories, as indicated by the use of `os.listdir(filepath)` and the line `print("local directory found succesfully!")`.

Change the paths to the actual remote and local filename to get and you should be good to go.